# Heroku platform credits

Tags: heroku

I just verfied my Heroku account and now Heroku tells me that I have 161$ Platform credits. Does that mean that I have to pay 161$?

I wouldnt know how I possible could accumulated such a bill in such a short time...

Best

Comment: This is a better question for Heroku support, but generally speaking "credits" would mean that you can use that much worth of services without paying. It's like a gift certificate.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it should be directed to Heroku support.

Answer (score 9):

It means you have got 161$ to spend (only on Hobby Dynos, in case you're a student).

[See the official Heroku post here](https://help.heroku.com/Z3RHNRHD/how-does-the-github-student-developer-pack-work)